# Using named scopes in Ruby on Rails 4 on associated models

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

My app consists of 3 models:

`FashionModel`
`Measurement` 
`ModelProfile`

```
class FashionModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  has_one :model_profile
  has_one :measurement
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :model_profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :measurement
end


class ModelProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fashion_model
end


class Measurement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fashion_model
end
```

The schema is roughly as follows:

```
create_table "fashion_models", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name",             limit: 25
    t.string   "last_name",              limit: 25
    t.string   "email",                  limit: 255, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         null: false
    t.string   "password_digest",        limit: 255
    t.string   "password_reset_token",   limit: 255
    t.datetime "password_reset_sent_at"
  end

  create_table "measurements", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "fashion_model_id", limit: 4
    t.decimal  "feet",                         precision: 10
    t.decimal  "inches",                       precision: 10
    t.decimal  "bust",                         precision: 10, default: 36
    t.decimal  "waist",                        precision: 10, default: 28
    t.decimal  "hips",                         precision: 10, default: 36
    t.decimal  "shoes",                        precision: 10
    t.integer  "dress",            limit: 4
    t.string   "eyes",             limit: 255
    t.string   "hair",             limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                                               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                               null: false
  end

  create_table "model_profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "fashion_model_id", limit: 4
    t.string   "phone_number",     limit: 255
    t.date     "birthdate"
    t.text     "bio",              limit: 65535
    t.string   "location",         limit: 255,                  default: "Venice"
    t.string   "gender",           limit: 255
    t.decimal  "rate",                           precision: 10, default: 100
    t.string   "profile_picture",  limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                                                       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                                       null: false
  end

  add_index "model_profiles", ["fashion_model_id"], name: "index_model_profiles_on_fashion_model_id", using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "bookings", "fashion_models"
  add_foreign_key "fashion_model_photos", "fashion_models"
end
```

I am trying to filter out data based on the input. For example someone searches for a model with height 5'8", with black eyes, and brown hair, I should display only those models by querying the database.

Therefore, I am trying to use named scopes in the model. I am not sure how do I scope the attributes of the `measurement` table by writing a scope in the `FashionModel` model.

I read a few resources online and from what I understood, I wrote something like

```
scope :eye_color, includes(:measurement).where(measurement: { eyes: "Amber" })
```

Though I don't want to hardcode `Amber` into the eyes field, I get an error in my console when trying to access this scope. I do something like

```
a = FashionModel.all
a.eye_color
```

This gives me an and `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)`.

I also tried doing this

```
scope :eye_color, -> (eye_color) { where eyes: eye_color }
```

and then calling it by `a.eye_color("Amber")`, which in turn gave me a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'measurement' for Class`.

So basically I want to scope into the child models from the parent model.
Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Define your scope as:

```
scope :eye_color, ->(eye_color) {
  includes(:measurements).where(measurements: {eyes: eye_color}) 
}
```

And then query with a param like:

```
FashionModel.eye_color("Amber")
```

Comment: I get a syntax error `unexpected ')', expecting` `unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'`

Comment: I tried doing that. It gives me something like `SELECT 'fashion_models'.'id' AS t0_r0, 'fashion_models'.'first_name' AS t0_r1, 'fashion_models'.'last_name' AS t0_r2` and then throws an error:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'measurement.eyes'`